# changing file path model from Linux (/) to windows (\) in Java Script

Tags: javascript, str-replace

I have some file paths in Unix system and I am trying to convert them to windows based path using java script `Replace` function.

For instance: I am trying to convert : `//File/Test/images` to  `\\File\Test\images`

I am trying to achieve this by using **string.replace** which is

```
var winpath =oldPath.replace(/:|\\/g, "\/");
```

is this a correct way to replace the `/` to `\`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex literal with the g modifier, and escape the "/"  with a "\" so it doesn't clash with the delimiters.

```
var myStr = '//File/Test/images', replacement = '';
var replaced = myStr.replace(/\//g, replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var winPath = oldPath.replace(/\//g,"\\");
```

`/\//g` will match all the `/` and replaces it with `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, and escape `\` char in `replace()` function second param

```
var oldPath = "//File/Test/images";
var winpath = oldPath.replace(/[\/]/g, "\\");
alert(winpath)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1gnou2a0/)